# Problem getting directory or file short name in batch file under windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path

As a java software programmer, I'm used to create batch scripts for my software.
In these scripts, I get the short name of the folders I work with, in order to make sure the software will work with command prompt (cmd).
But then, one of my users on Windows 10 told me the software did not work on his computer.
After some researches, I discovered that the algorithm that used to give me the folder short name did not work on his computer

I tried the same test code on various computers with different windows versions, and only on his computer I just could not get the expected short names.

Test code extracting the short name  (sorry for the french text: it is for french users):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO -------------------------------------
@ECHO Version de Windows :
ver
@ECHO -------------------------------------
REM Test de nom court
SET ROOT_DIR=%~dp0
SET TMP_DIR=""
REM for "usebackq delims=" /d %%I in ("%ROOT_DIR%") do (
for /d %%I in ("%ROOT_DIR%") do (
  if %TMP_DIR% == "" (
    SET TMP_DIR=%%~sI
  )
)
@ECHO test nom court du dossier courant: '%TMP_DIR%'
PAUSE
```

For example, with this folder (with deliberate long name) and given batch code:

```
D:\aa aaaaaa aa\vcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv\ccccccccccggggggggggggttttttttttttttttrrrrrrrrr           dsdqkdhqk  ;
```

- On a windows 7 computer, I get this result:

```
-------------------------------------
Version de Windows :

Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
-------------------------------------
test nom court du dossier courant: 'D:\AAAAAA~1\VCXVVV~1\CCCCCC~1\'
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

- On my user's windows 10 computer, I get this result:

```
-------------------------------------
Version de Windows :

Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.1040]
-------------------------------------
test nom court du dossier courant: 'D:\aa aaaaaa aa\vcxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv\ccccccccccggggggggggggttttttttttttttttrrrrrrrrr           dsdqkdhqk  ;'
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Due to this kind of answer, my batch scripts won't work because the command prompt will raise errors for too long lines.

Does anyone have any idea about how to get the expected short names on windows 10?

I don't know if it will help (I'm not a windows expert), but I did some research with regedit on his computer, and I found these:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem\NtfsAllowExtendedCharacter8dot3Rename = 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation = 2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsAllowExtendedCharacter8dot3Rename = 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation = 2
```

Thank you by advance for any solution to that problem.

Regards,

Comment: `dir /x` list shortnames.. so if you execute something like this you'll get the idea `@for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('dir /ad /x ^| find "~"') do @echo %%~i`

Comment: To enable the creation of 8.3 filenames, you could try either, `"%__AppDir__%fsutil.exe" Behavior Set Disable8dot3 0` or `"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem /V NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F`. In both cases you should run the commands 'As administrator'. I will also add that you should really try to explain what the issue is with using the long filenames. There are potential workarounds for some issues and those would be better than having to get all end users machines Admin configured.

Comment: dir /x won't help (I already know this command), because it lists the files in your folder, but doesn't give you the short path of your folder.

Comment: Concerning 8.3 file names creation, I just checked on his computer if "c:\progra~1" exists, and it does exist. So, it probably means this functionality is already activated. But again, I'm not sure because I'm not a windows expert....

Comment: To detail my problem: I need to configure some variables for my program, like CLASSPATH. With the long names, the command prompt raises a too long line error. With the short names, there is no problem. And I never encountered this error before. So for me, it is a windows 10 specific problem... Anyway, I will try to change the value of "NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation" to 0 and see whether it changes the behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: I just checked the values of NtfsAllowExtendedCharacter8dot3Rename and NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation on the Windows 7 system (on which the short name algorithm does work) : They are the same ones as those on windows 10. So I'm not sure this is the explanation. I guess something changed on windows 10, but I don't know what...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by it does not show the shortnames if the directory. That is exactly what the `for` loop does that I posted.

Comment: A value of `0` enables applications that cannot process long file names and computers that use different code pages to find the files. A value `2` sets the 8.3 naming convention creation on a per volume basis. Perhaps therefore it's the volume or even it's file system that's different for the other PC user. At this stage you should post your actual code with the long filenames, together with the actual name of the software being used and sufficient information for us to replicate your issue. We could then try to fix the code without having to resort to short file naming.

Comment: OK, I understand that behaviour. I will try to apply the "0" value on my user's computer as soon as possible and keep you informed about the results. Thank you very much @compo .

Comment: Thank you very much @Compo : you definitely were right.
My user has windows 10 pro with a SSD, and on SSD, the default behaviour seems to be not allowing short file names.
I put the registry value to 0 using this command:
'''
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\" -Name NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation -Value 0
'''
After rebooting the computer and installing my software to a new folder, it did work.

Comment: The only limitation of this is that it doesn't work in previously created folders : these folders were not created with short names, so there is no possibility to get their short name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Compo had the right answer:
My user has windows 10 pro with a SSD.
On windows 10 (at least pro), the default behaviour concerning SSD seems to be "do not allow short file names".

So, I put the "NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation" registry value to 0 using this command with PowerShell run as administrator:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\" -Name NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation -Value 0
```

After rebooting the computer and installing my software to a new folder, it did work.

The only limitation of this is that **it doesn't work in previously created folders**: these folders were not created with short names, so there is no possibility to get their short name...